# Value of type 'UIButton' has no member 'enumerate'

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

```
func addButtonConstraints(buttons:UIButton, mainView:UIView) {
    for(index, buttons) in buttons.enumerate{
```

but xcode give me this error --->Value of type 'UIButton' has no member 'enumerate'

Answer (score 1):

The `enumerate` property is a member of `Array`. So here there is only one `UIButton` it can't be enumerated unless it is `[UIButton]`.

Replace:

```
func addButtonConstraints(buttons:UIButton, mainView:UIView) {
    for(index, buttons) in buttons.enumerate{
```

With:

```
func addButtonConstraints(buttons: [UIButton], mainView: UIView) {  
    for (index, button) in buttons.enumerated() {
```

Comment: It doesn't work, and the same error happened (totally same) when i replaced it. i am workig on it now, will subscribe solution when i finger it out.

Comment: That's not likely. The enumeration part should have worked. This solution is tested and working. You're probably making some other mistake.

Comment: Hi Dear Frank: i think i just finger it out but not with your answer,  i suspect that we use Swift version.

Comment: my solution as below:

Comment: func addButtonConstraints(buttons: [UIButton], mainView: UIView) {
        for(index, button) in buttons.enumerated() {

Comment: How is this different from what I've posted above? I've posted the exact same statement above.

Comment: i replace "enumerate" with " enumerated ()", it really works

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I missed that part. But, it's probably be considered as a typo. You should have gotten auto-complete for `enumerated()` right after you made the above change. Anyways I'll update the typo too to my answer for future reference.